# How to filter and style a data table

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am making a Shiny app that will allow the user to choose a dataframe from a dropdown that will then be formatted into a  DT data table. I want the user to be able to filter the data by column value and I want certain rows to have red text. Here's the code for the app:

global.R:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Name = c("a", "b", "c"),
                  Parameter = c("pH", "pH", "pH"),
                  Amount = c(7, 7.5, 6.8),
                  Violation = c("No", "No", "Yes"))

df2 <- data.frame(Name = c("d", "e", "f"),
                  Parameter = c("pH", "pH", "pH"),
                  Amount = c(6.7, 7.2, 7.3),
                  Violation = c("Yes", "No", "No"))
```

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

    titlePanel("Title"),

    fluidRow(
        selectInput(inputId = "df_test",
                    label = "Select DF",
                    choices = c("DF 1" = "df1", 
                                "DF 2" = "df2"), 
                    selected = "DF 1", 
                    width = "50%"),
    
        
        DT::dataTableOutput("test_table")
    )
))
```

server.R:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    
    output$test_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
        get(input$df_test)
    })

})
```

I want to add filter bars to the top of the data table and make the "Yes" values in the Violation column red. In a regular R script I would do this.

```
datatable(df1, filter = "top", 
                                options = list(pageLength = 25, autoWidth = TRUE)) %>% 
  formatStyle("Violation", valueColumns = "Violation", color = styleEqual("Yes", 'red'))
```

How can I implement this in the Shiny app so that the chosen dataframe from selectInput is formatted like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could just wrap the `datatable` code around the `get(input$df_test)`

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(Name = c("a", "b", "c"),
                  Parameter = c("pH", "pH", "pH"),
                  Amount = c(7, 7.5, 6.8),
                  Violation = c("No", "No", "Yes"))

df2 <- data.frame(Name = c("d", "e", "f"),
                  Parameter = c("pH", "pH", "pH"),
                  Amount = c(6.7, 7.2, 7.3),
                  Violation = c("Yes", "No", "No"))


ui = fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Title"),
  
  fluidRow(
    selectInput(inputId = "df_test",
                label = "Select DF",
                choices = c("DF 1" = "df1", 
                            "DF 2" = "df2"), 
                selected = "DF 1", 
                width = "50%"),
    
    
    DT::dataTableOutput("test_table")
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$test_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    
    
    DT::datatable(get(input$df_test), filter = "top", 
              options = list(pageLength = 25, autoWidth = TRUE)) %>% 
      DT::formatStyle("Violation", valueColumns = "Violation", color = DT::styleEqual("Yes", 'red')) 
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

-ouput

[image]